# How do I parse dates in embedded lists?

Tags: orientdb

Running the following query

```
insert into V set events = [{"on": date("2005-09-08 04:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "UTC")}, {"on": date("2005-09-08 04:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "UTC")}]
```

Results in the following `events` on the new vertex: `[{"on":"_NOT_PARSED_"},{"on":"_NOT_PARSED_"}]`.

Is this a bug, or a known limitation? If not, how do I embed multiple dates?

Answer (score 0):

Pass them as string, but respect the format in database (you can change it with [`ALTER DATABASE`](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/SQL-Alter-Database.html) command. Working example:

```
insert into V set events = [{"on": "2005-09-08 04:00:00"}, {"on": "2005-09-08 04:00:00"}]
```

Comment: are there any plans to support dates in embedded documents/lists?

Comment: This will be supported in 3.0 (we're already working on that). When 3.0 will be available? Around September 2015.

Comment: "we're already working on that" -> I thought you were working on 2.1 :) Anyway good to hear this will be supported, thanks!

Comment: BTW @Lvca, is there any github issue we can track?